# How to restart an animation stopped before completion but with different parameters

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an animation where two containers collide with each other. I want the containers to reverse back with animation to their respective starting offset. The containers move along varied paths and duration.

[image]

As seen in the animation gif attached the green and red containers collide and jump back to their starting offsets rather than sliding back.

Here is the code I used to make the GIF, in my actual code I'm using rectangle intersection to check when the containers collide.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  List<AnimationController> _controller = List(2);
  List<Animation<Offset>> _animation = List(2);
  List<Tween<Offset>> tween = List(2);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tween[0] = Tween(begin: Offset(0, 10), end: Offset(200, 10));
    tween[1] = Tween(begin: Offset(200, 10), end: Offset(0, 10));
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      _controller[i] =
          AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 1));

      _animation[i] = tween[i].animate(_controller[i])
        ..addListener(
          () {
            setState(
              () {
                print(
                    '${_animation[0].value.dx.toInt()}:${_animation[0].value.dy.toInt()} ${_animation[1].value.dx.toInt()}:${_animation[1].value.dy.toInt()}');
                if (((_animation[0].value.dx) / 2).round() ==
                    ((_animation[1].value.dx) / 2).round()) {
                  _controller[0].stop();
                  _controller[1].stop();

                  _controller[0].reset();
                  _controller[1].reset();

                  Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100)).then((_) {
                    tween[0] = Tween(
                        begin: Offset(
                            _animation[0].value.dx, _animation[0].value.dy),
                        end: Offset(0, 10));
                    tween[1] = Tween(
                        begin: Offset(
                            _animation[1].value.dx, _animation[1].value.dy),
                        end: Offset(200, 10));

                    _animation[0] = tween[0].animate(_controller[0]);
                    _animation[1] = tween[1].animate(_controller[1]);

                    _controller[0].forward();
                    _controller[1].forward();
                  });
                }
              },
            );
          },
        );
    }

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
      (_) => _afterLayout(),
    );
  }

  void _afterLayout() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      _controller[i].forward();
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
      _controller[i].dispose();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("collision"),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: double.infinity,
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    left: _animation[0] != null ? _animation[0].value.dx : 0,
                    top: _animation[0] != null ? _animation[0].value.dy : 0,
                    child: Container(
                      width: 50,
                      height: 50,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    left: _animation[1] != null ? _animation[1].value.dx : 0,
                    top: _animation[1] != null ? _animation[1].value.dy : 0,
                    child: Container(
                      width: 50,
                      height: 50,
                      color: Colors.green,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _controller[0].reset();
                _controller[1].reset();

                tween[0] = Tween(begin: Offset(0, 10), end: Offset(200, 10));
                tween[1] = Tween(begin: Offset(200, 10), end: Offset(0, 10));

                _controller[0].duration = Duration(seconds: 1);
                _controller[1].duration = Duration(seconds: 1);

                _animation[0] = tween[0].animate(_controller[0]);
                _animation[1] = tween[1].animate(_controller[1]);

                _controller[0].forward();
                _controller[1].forward();
              },
              child: Text("Animate"),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want the containers to smoothly slide back to their respective starting offsets with animation.

Comment: To go back to the same position use ```reverse``` for the ```_controller```. Also do not ```reset``` it.

Comment: Reverse has the same effect as above. The container does not slide back but just appears at the position.

Comment: You are doing a ```reset``` which is not needed when you use ```reverse```.

Comment: You are correct, please add your comment as answer I'll accept it. And thanks for your time, I was able to resolve the issue with your help.

Comment: I've changed my comment into an answer, if you want you can accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will add a bit of explanation here to help others maybe.

Animations in flutter are controlled by an `AnimationController`. You can control one ore more animations using a single `AnimationController` ( you can use same controller if you want to have animations triggered simultaneously).

Now, to start an animation (or all animations linked to the same controller) you can use `forward()` method. The `forward()` method accepts a parameter that specify from which point on should the animation continue, the parameter value is between 0...1.

If you want to do the animation in backwards, the controller has a method called `reverse()` which will perform the animation in the reverse order. Same, the method accepts a parameter with value from 0 to 1, if no parameter is specified the animation will "reverse" from the last state.

Note in order to have a reverse animation you should **not** call `reset()` on the controller. `reset()` method will set all the values of the controller to the initial ones.